# UICollectionView and UITableView calls scrollViewDidScroll after a pop on UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

My situation:

I've a view controller `A` with a `UICollectionView` on it. I push a new view controller `B`and when I come back (with back button) from `B` to `A`, the `UIScrollViewDelegate` on `A` call `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`.

I've the same behavior with a view controller with a `UITableView`.

This drive me crazy...
Ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in A controller or disable from storyboard.